# Errors when compiling with include files (Own classes)

Tags: c++, class, compilation, include

Information:Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, Windows 8 Professional, C++.
I Have a problem...

QIClassStringOperations.hpp

```
#include "Q.hpp"
class QIClassStringOperations
{
    public:
        virtual void FromString(const QString& Str) = 0;
        virtual QString ToString() = 0;
};
```

Q.hpp

```
#include "QString.hpp"
```

QString.hpp

```
template <typename Type> class CString
{
    //...
};
typedef CString<char> QString;
```

in compiling i have this error:

```
c:\...\QIClassStringOperations.hpp(13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Problem with this line:

```
virtual void FromString(const QString& Str) = 0;
```

Sorry for my bad English :).
Can you help me?

Comment: Should work. Does it work if you declare your function like this: `virtual void FromString(const CString<char>& Str) = 0;` ?
The type and class definitions are not wraped into some namespaces?

Comment: Nothing happens when i replace QString with CString<char>. Every code is contained in namespace QEngine (my small framework). I think maybe is project error or something wrong in project settings.

Comment: The line number from the error message suggests, that you omitted some code. Does the error occur with the exact code you pasted, too? Could you otherwise provide a minimal example which fails to compile with the mentioned error message?

Comment: I think that include files don't see them.
I write that line in QString.hpp/QIClassStringOperations.hpp:
#include "Q.hpp"
QIClassStringOperations.hpp
don't see QString.hpp
#include "QString.hpp" #include "QIClassStringOperations.hpp"
QString.hpp and QClassStringOperations.hpp are included and including Q.hpp...
but they don't see (QString don't see QIClassStringOperations and QIClassStringOperations don't see QString)...

Comment: The code as you pasted it should definitely compile. I  tested it with all your includes. It works. So as already said, you should provide more code. Also paste other errors (if there are any) which the compiler finds.

Comment: So your `Q.hpp` includes both `QIClassStringOperations.hpp` and `QString.hpp` and all headers have proper include Guards? And you want to access `QIClassStringOperations` from within `QString.hpp` and vice versa? Than your problem is that you can't write two headers that depend on each other. The include guards ensure that one header is parsed first and the content of the other header is not available at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like QString in not reconized as a type?
Where do you declare QString?

Comment: I Declare QString in QString.hpp (in the same project) as typedef of template CString<char>. VS2012 normally see this class in project and highlight QString.

Answer (score 0):

You should include **#include "QString.hpp"** in **Q.hpp** where you declare the class QIClassStringOperations because it should know what QString is. Otherwise compiler gives an error.

For more details visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696.aspx

Comment: I include this file (#include "QString.hpp") in Q.hpp, but I declare the class in QIClassStringOperations.hpp. Should I include (#include "QString.hpp") in QIClassStringOperations.hpp file? or pre-declaration in Q.hpp file?